# Shift click to add value to object without using angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

In HTML file:

```
...
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="addFruit('Apple')">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="addFruit('Banana')">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="addFruit('Coconut')">Coconut</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

Controller:

```
...
$scope.addFruit = function(fruitName) {
    $scope.fruitObject.name = fruitName;
};

$scope.fruitObject = {
    name: '',
}
```

So, if I click the link in the HTML file, it changes *fruitObject.name*.  I want to add the function that if I click the link with **shift key**, the value will be added to the *fruitObject*:

```
$scope.fruitObject = {
    name: ['Apple', 'Banana']
}
```

1. Can I do this without using a angular directive?
2. And if I can/can't, could you write an example code?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6QcEc/

Comment: Not sure how to do it in Angular, but you can reference the `shiftKey` property of the Event object at any time to see whether the Shift key is being held down.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the docs [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) can give you the [$event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) object which can tell you if the shift key is pressed.

```
<li><a href="#" ng-click="addFruit('Apple',$event)">Apple</a></li>
            ...
$scope.addFruit = function(fruitName,$event) {
    $scope.fruitObject.name = fruitName;
    if($event.shiftKey){
         //logic
    }
};
```

Comment: Aha '$event' is the key.  Thanks!

Comment: when I click the link with a shift key, it selects the text with block.  How can I prevent from selecting text block?

Comment: Could be a separate search but your answer would be to add the following styles:  
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;